# I can't see any of my sub processes to be called,when I use apply_async() func of multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python

I know the basic usage of multiprocessing about pools,and I use apply_async() func to avoid block,my problem code such like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time

q = Queue(maxsize=20)
script = "my_path/my_exec_file"

def initQueue():
   ...

def test_func(queue):
    print 'Coming'
    While True:
     do_sth
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initQueue()
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    for i in xrange(11,20):
        result = pool.apply_async(test_func, (q,))
    pool.close()
    while True:
        if q.empty():
            print 'Queue is emty,quit'
            break
        print 'Main Process Lintening'
        time.sleep(2)
```

The results output are always Main Process Linstening,I can;t find word 'Coming'..
The code above has no syntax error and no any Exceptions.
Any one can help, thanks!

Comment: Do you ever wait for the pool to do any work or always call `pool.close()` right away?

Comment: The first time I run,it can;t work,the today I run again,it work.But there are other problems:In test_func(),what it gonna do is exec m another .py(the script is like spider and it can run without any problem).I can see only one line 'Coming' and just stop there to exec script.But I wanna see apply_async() work,I means,at least another 'Coming' should be output

Comment: The main script, I want main process to monitor my queue,and if I substitute while in test_func() for displaying my processs name,I always get 'Main Process'